# PS2 to USB adapter for ps2 keyboard not working properly with Shift + [key]

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ps2-keyboard

I have ps2 keyboard. but my laptop running windows 10 and does not have ps2 socket

I bought ps2 to USB adapter and all keys work fine in typing. but in gaming when I usually use sprint by pressing shift + w most of the time, the sprint stops I need to press the keys again to sprint.

I tried doing a simple test by doing shift + w in notepad and it works fine no problem. the keys shift + w didn't stop registering in notepad. only stop in games

I tried different ps2 keyboards same thing. is there a way to fix the shift + [key] problem?

Update: USB keyboards works fine in games

Comment: Check if USB keyboards work correctly in games

Comment: usb keyboards works fine and i update my question with that